# How to use testnet with Zelcore?

Tags: pact, pact-lang

How do I test on the Zelcore test net? In Chainweaver I can explicitly select testnet and have all the transactions go that way.
However , I can't select "testnet" from Zelcore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The testnet backend was already present on my install.

1. Open a wallet and click "Manage Assets" > Add Asset > TESTKDA
2. Click on the added TESTKDA asset. Click receive.
3. Open https://faucet.testnet.chainweb.com/ in your browser. Choose 'Create and Fund'
4. Paste the public key part of your accountname in the first form field (accountname without k:) and the accountname (with k:) in the second.
5. Click on the plus next to your public key and then on the 'Create and Fund Account'
6. A few minutes later your testKda coins will appear in your Zelcore wallet

Go to the main wallet overview and select one of the other wallets. eg mining.

1. You will have to add the testkda asset again. Click on receive to copy the account address
2. Go to the first account and send a bit of your 20 testKda from the first to another wallet eg mining

If you select the wrong account or a different chain than where the funds are you will get "error obtaining Kadena transactions", make sure to select the correct wallet, chain and accountname (with or without k:).
To double-check the actual status of the accounts use https://balance.chainweb.com with api.testnet.chainweb.com in the "chainweb server" field and your accountname in the last field.